# How to access model hasMany Relation with where condition in lighthouse graphql?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql

I have a model **Media** with a **type** column. I want to get files by type with a dynamic where condition.

**Model**

```
public function images () {
    return $this->hasMany(Media::class, 'recipe_id');
}

public function collection($type) {
    return $this->images()->where('collection', '=', $type);
}
```

**Schema.graphql**

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    images: [Media] @hasMany
}

type Media {
    id: ID!
    collection: String!
    name: String!
    file: String!
    mime_type: String!
    user: User @belongsTo
}
```

The media relationship will give all the images related to this user but I want to access the collection method inside the model.

Answer (score 1):

That should make a trick, and you do not need collection in your Model

**Schema.graphql**

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    images (type: String @eq): [Media] @hasMany
}

type Media {
    id: ID!
    type: String
    name: String!
    file: String!
    mime_type: String!
    user: User @belongsTo
}
```

Or you can do that simply by custom Query but solutions above seams to be more elegant